# Using Conditional branch algorithm in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, algorithm, conditional

I have a question regarding using the Conditional Branch algorithm in the Graphical Model Builder.

I am building a rather complicated model with many branches but not every branch needs to be used every time. So I want to use the Conditional Branch algorithm to check the `"art"` column of the attribute table from my input layer and to only run that branch if a given value is present, PX or QX in this particular case.

The model will have at least 15 branches when I am finished but usually only a few will be needed per job.

So, I need to use the Conditional Branch algorithm as a kind of if/else filter where if the value is present it runs the branch elsewise it ignores that branch and moves on to the next one.

How do I set up the Conditional Branch so that it ignores that branch unless the value is present?

(Pic isn't my main model, just an example)

[image: basic model]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created a model with an input point layer.

A conditional branch with two conditions:

1. If there is an `A` in the `art` column: The points get buffered
2. If not it will create rectangles around the points.

Start by renaming the layer to `inlayer`

Create a conditional branch with the condition `aggregate(layer:='inlayer', aggregate:='count', expression:="art", filter:="art" IN('A'))>0`

([IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp))

It will count the number of values in the art column where the value is A. If more than 0 the branch will be True.

Create another branch with the opposite condition:
`aggregate(layer:='inlayer', aggregate:='count', expression:="art", filter:="art" IN('A'))<1`

[image]

Use the branches as dependecies to the next algorithms:
[image]

[image]